# Creating an listview which displays records

Tags: java, android, listview

```
          outputfile=       Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/recording.3gp";;
    audiorecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    audiorecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    audiorecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    audiorecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    audiorecorder.setOutputFile(outputfile);
    record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try{
                audiorecorder.prepare();
                audiorecorder.start();
            }
            catch (IllegalStateException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            record.setEnabled(true);
            stop.setEnabled(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Recording started",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        }
    });

      stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

        audiorecorder.stop();
        audiorecorder.release();
        audiorecorder =null;
      stop.setEnabled(false);
    play.setEnabled(true);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record successfully    recorded",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

     }
    });
         play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
    MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();
    try{
        m.setDataSource(outputfile);
    }

    catch ( IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    try{
        m.prepare();

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    m.start();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
    });
```

This is the record ive created .I created another intent which contains a listview which i want to display in it the records SAVED.
any idea how to save the records? and then how to display them in the listview?

Comment: Save the records to the device's internal storage and list them in a `ListView`. What have you tried?

Comment: and how do i save them in the device?

Comment: Well, in the code in your question you are already doing that. `outputfile =       Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/recording.3gp";` and `audiorecorder.setOutputFile(outputfile);`.

Comment: and how do i display them in a listview?

Comment: A Google search for "how to list files in listview android" would probably do half the trick.